# How can you make a 2d array object

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm trying to make a static 2D array object. I came up with one where it has to be initialized by the user but for my purposes I want it to be already initialized.

```java
String str;
int temp = 0;
int check = 0;
Plot[][] farm = new Plot[4][3];
ExperimentalFarm p = new ExperimentalFarm(farm);
for (int i = 0; i < farm.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < farm[i].length; j++) {
        str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name the crop");
        temp = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the yield"));
        farm[i][j] = new Plot(str, temp);
    }
}
```

I'm also trying to return an object from a class to the client. For example, I want to get which player did the best. I want to have their name and their score. How do I return that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're doing it. `Plot[][] farm = new Plot[4][3];` makes a new 2D array (technically, java does not have 2D arrays. At all. What you can do, however, is a 1D array, whose elements are themselves arrays, which is exactly what that does: `farm` is of type: "An array whose component types are arrays whose component types are Plot objects", and `new Plot[4][3]` initializes this array to contain 3 sub-arrays, and each sub-array is initialized to contain an array capable of holding 4 plots.

But that just makes room for plots, it doesn't instantiate 12 plot objects, you have to do that yourself. You are doing just that in the code you pasted: That loop structure ends up running the stuff within ("Name the crop", etc) a grand total of 12 times, meaning, `new Plot` is executed 12 times, you want that to happen.

Here's how to e.g. do it yourself:

```
Plot[][] farm = new Plot[4][3];
for (int i = 0; i < farm.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < farm[i].length; j++) {
    farm[i][j] = new Plot("barren", 0);
  }
}
```